# 3D user interface

Tags: windows, software-development, c#, gui, 3d

What software would be good for implementing 3D user interface control system. Below is the image of automated guided vehicle control system which is representing in real time where the vehicle is. So which software would be good to draw and then represent animations of such a system. I am planing to build something similar but much simpler for my project. But I would like 3D capability and simulation interaction.

Would WPF be a good fit for this task or is there any better software.

The target platform is Windows but also other are viable. Just looking the best tools for the job.

[image]

Comment: You mention WPF, so I imagine that you are targeting Windows. You might want to add an o/s tag to clarify (several, if it will be cross platform). Also, are you constrained as to programming language, or are you will to learn a new one?

Comment: Maybe SketchUp (formerly: Google Sketchup)? @TheMentor

Comment: I know C# but I am not constrained to any particular language.

Comment: @Davidenko You mean sketch up as drawing the model and then importing it in some programming language like c# where you can implementing simulations and other stuff?

Comment: I don't know if that's is possible, but you have plugins like SketchyPhysics that can run simulations. I don't know if it's possible to connect the objects in the model to the real world objects. @TheMentor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [unity3d](http://unity3d.com), it is a bit overkill for what you want but it offers a very good 3d engine and you can animate your objects with unity script (javascript-ish) or with C#.

There are a lot of free tutorials and the software itself is free too.

Answer (score 2):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) should do well.

It has a large community that provides Q/A-support and tutorials for free.
The software itself is free and open source as well.

```
Blender is a free and open source 3D animation suite. It supports the entirety of the 3D pipeline—modeling, rigging, animation, simulation, rendering, compositing and motion tracking,
```